# React detect component position change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to be able to detect position change of a component in my react application.

```
<div>
    <div>Dynamically rendered element</div>
    <div>Element to be absolutely positioned</div>
</div>
```

The dynamically rendered element is rendered based on ajax request so when I try to get the offset during `componentDidMount` I dont' get the offset when the div is actually rendered. How do I detect position change of a component in React?

Comment: can you try this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

Comment: @AravindS no I'm asking how I can detect the position change not how to get the position

Comment: did you try to get the offset value on the callback of `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: @AravindS yes but as I said, the component size changes after apollo request and that is after componentDidMount